# post message on facebook wall not working

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I want to post a message on facebook wall from our site. First I am getting error as

> Uncaught OAuthException: (#200), when trying to post on wall

Now I am not getting the error but the code is not working.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => APP_ID,
  'secret' => APP_SECRET,
  'cookie' => true,
  'req_perms' => 'email,read_stream,read_friendlists,publish_stream,offline_access,manage_pages',
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  } 
}
if (!empty($user_profile )) {
  $username = $user_profile['name'];
  $uid = $user_profile['id'];
  try {
    $post=$facebook->api("/".$uid."/feed", "post", array(
      'access_token' => $token,
      'message' => 'test',
    ));
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
```

But no message is coming what to do? Is there any problem while creating the application?

Comment: What did you do to correct the error?  Was it the try/catch blocks?

Comment: yes I use this code inside the try block                           $post=$facebook->api("/".$uid."/feed", "post", array(
                     'access_token' => $token,
             'message' => 'test',
               ));

Comment: So, presumably the error is still happening.  Have you recently edited your app's permissions in the facebook admin page?

Comment: facebook admin page? what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my wild guess, since our Comment Q&A wasn't going to work very well.

If you authorize your app with some set of permissions, and subsequently change the permissions that your app requests (at the app admin page), your existing authorization does not update to include the new permissions.  Your app will still function, but the actions that require the new permissions will fail.

You can test if this is causing your error by simply removing the app from your personal account app settings page, and re-approving the app with the new permissions.  If your problem vanishes, then congratulations.  If not, you'll need to do more detective work.  Your code appears to be fine.

Comment: Is there any problem while creating the application? while creating the application is we need to write any function for writing message on wall.

Comment: In some application we can see **This app can also:Post on your behalf, Access posts in your News Feed**. But in my application these were not seen. Is that any problem?

Comment: Yes.  That is probably the problem.  Your app needs to be configured to request those permissions.